# Testing variable against sqlite isn't working

Tags: bash, sqlite

I'm writing a script that will download certain subdirectories and their contents once only. To do that I've set up an sqlite database (dir.db) with one table (zero) and one column (episode, defined as variable character using VARCHAR(10)). This is used in the following script -

```
enter #!/bin/sh
set -x
cd ~/scripts/sqlite/remote/
Progs=( * )
for show in "${Progs[@]%*/}"; do
  cd ~/scripts/sqlite/
  exists=$( sqlite3 dir.db "select count(*) from zero where episode=\"?$show%/}\"" )
  if (( exists > 0 )); then
    echo "Show already downloaded"
  else
    cp ~/scripts/sqlite/remote/${show}/ -t ~/scripts/sqlite/home/ -R -v
    sqlite3 dir.db "insert into zero (episode) values ('${show}');"
    fi
done
exit 0
```

This script runs without error, but doesn't work :). If I put a directory in ~/scripts/sqlite/remote/ which is in dir.db, the directory should return 'Show already downloaded', but instead it copies.

Clearly the problem is here -

```
  exists=$( sqlite3 dir.db "select count(*) from zero where episode=\"?$show%/}\"" )
  if (( exists > 0 ));
```

but I don't know how to diagnose it - I got the code from elsewhere (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/bash-script-how-to-assign-variable-to-an-sqlite3-command-with-variable-embedded-4175453829/)

Any thoughts on how to fix would be welcome.

Comment: What is the `episode=` string supposed to look like exactly? The `}` there is likely not doing what you want. The `/` might also not be intended to be there (unless that's part of your query).

Comment: The $show variable is a subdirectory of ~/scripts/sqlite/remote/. In my testing I've used 'Alf' and 'Bert' as subdirs, the dirs in a real situation will b something like 'Better.Call.Saul.S01E03.720p.killer'. It's text. I've tried using a text table in dir.db instead of varchar, no effect.

Comment: I'll try deleting the / and see what happens.

Comment: Deleting the / had no effect. The scripts runs and the varialbes are added to dir.db, but the test against dir.db is not working

Comment: If the `$show` variable itself is exactly the string you want on the right-hand side of the `=` in `episode=` then you want `episode=\"$show\"`. If the `?` is part of the right-hand side too then `episode=\"?$show\"`, etc. But right now you have `%/}` there which appears to be erroneous (leftover from the expansion of `"${Progs[@]%*/}"` but that is doing more work then you need to be doing to `$show`.

Comment: @Etan, this fixed it, thank you. I used [code]episode=\"${show}\"['code'] and this worked. Maybe the curly brackets aren't necessary, but its consistent with the rest of the script and it did work. Thanks again.

Comment: Both `$show` and `${show}` are perfectly valid variable references. Your problem was an unbalanced `}` and the `%/` remnant from the other expansion.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
exists=$( sqlite3 dir.db "select count(*) from zero where episode=\"?$show%/}\"" )
```

That line expands to (assuming `show=foobar`):

```
exists=$( sqlite3 dir.db "select count(*) from zero where episode=\"?foobar%/}\"" )
```

Which, unless your episode name is `?foobar%/}` is not going to match.

The `%/}` is remnant from the `"${Progs[@]%*/}` expansion but in that context `%*/` is performing string manipulation on the `${Progs[@]}` variable expansion and is also an unbalanced trailing `}`.

Either

```
exists=$( sqlite3 dir.db "select count(*) from zero where episode=\"$show\"" )
```

or

```
exists=$( sqlite3 dir.db "select count(*) from zero where episode=\"${show}\"" )
```

should do what you want (and are identical).